# Simple cache profiling API

Tags: c, linux

Is there a way I can access the (Intel]) hardware counters for each core **programmatically**?  (that is, no `perf`, `perfmon`, or `valgrind`, and I should add "simple", so no `PAPI`, e.g.) I'd like to know (for each core) how many L1-LLC cache hits/misses it (= a certain program running on that core) incurred in. This is for Linux 3.2.0-32, C, and using GCC.

Comment: LTTng (Linux Trace Toolkit Next Generation) is used for Tracing of HardWare, Driver, and Binary Reverse Engineering in Linux. You can look into it's source code to understand how it access hardware registers.

Comment: I guess, Intel forums will able to guide you better in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The performance counters in the processor can not be read from "user-mode" code, so you need some sort of kernel module to do this. Once you have that, it's not terribly hard, there are a number of MSR's.

You can perhaps also use /dev/cpu/core-number/msr to read the values without a kernel module.

To describe all the details of how you do this is a little too much for an answer (unless I copy'n'paste the entire section of Intel's programmers manual (Vol3) - which I don't think is quite what we want here...)